# Merge excecution logs into a report

Tags: python, c, matlab, logging, report

I insert some strobes into a C source code in order to obtain interesting information about every execution.
At the moment i print the information in a file at every execution. I have this kind of list:

- property1: value1
- property2: value2
- {those values are related to 2 different executions}
- property1: value3
- property2: value4

What i want is:

- property1: value1+value3
- property2: value2+value4

I'd like to generate a report in an effective way. I'd prefer to use MATLAB or Python.
The user roippi gave me a great answer for Python. I am interested in doing the same in MATLAB too.

Any pointer?

Here it is my actual input:

- *S*[10] 1
- *S*[0] 1
- *S*[1] 1
- *S*[2] 0
- *S*[3] 1
- *S*[4] 1
- *S*[5] 4
- *S*[6] 4
- *S*[7] 0
- *S*[8] 0
- *S*[9] 1
- *S*[10] 1
- *S*[0] 1
- *S*[1] 1
- *S*[2] 0
- *S*[3] 1
- *S*[4] 1
- *S*[5] 4
- *S*[6] 4
- *S*[7] 0
- *S*[8] 0
- *S*[9] 1

Comment: Any pointer to your effort so far?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Can you give a concrete (formatted) example of input and output?

Comment: Sure. In MATLAB I read my formatted data from file using textscan.
So I have a cell array. But I'm still wondering if it is more elegant to use instead join over multiple files.

Comment: Yes. The input is concrete and it is really simple:
For every execution of the C application I fprintf the information.
This information, for now, consists in a Counter_ID (i imagine it as a String) and an integer value e.g. 0,1,2. They are separated by whitespace. So we have:
- _S_[10] 1
* _S_[0] 1
* _S_[1] 1
* _S_[2] 0
* _S_[3] 1
* _S_[4] 1
* _S_[5] 4
* _S_[6] 4
* _S_[7] 0
* _S_[8] 0
* _S_[9] 1
* _S_[10] 1
* _S_[0] 1
* _S_[1] 1
* _S_[2] 0
* _S_[3] 1
* _S_[4] 1
* _S_[5] 4
* _S_[6] 4
* _S_[7] 0
* _S_[8] 0
* _S_[9] 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're looking to post-process your log file into a different file?  Easy enough in python:

infile:

```
prop1 thing
prop2 stuff
prop3 junk
prop1 something
prop2 whatever
```

python:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)

with open('infile') as f:
    for line in f:
        k,v = line.strip().split()
        d[k].append(v)
```

Then format your output:

```
for k,v in sorted(d.items()):
    print('{}: {}'.format(k,'+'.join(v)))

prop1: thing+something
prop2: stuff+whatever
prop3: junk
```

Replacing `print` with whatever actual file write operations you want to do.

Comment: i do like your answer: clean and efficient!
Am I asking too much if I wish to do the same in MATLAB too?

Answer (score 0):

If the value is an integer and you are adding all the values for a property, here's another way in python:

```
infile = file("input.txt", 'r')
outfile = file("output.txt", 'w')

from collections import defaultdict
props = defaultdict(int)

for line in infile:
   p, v = line.split()
   props[p] += int(v)

for p, v in sorted(props.items()):
    outfile.write("%s: %d\n" % (p,v))
```

The output will be sorted but it's not a natural sort, you would have to add more python code for that.

Comment: have you thought of defaultdict(int)?

Comment: I thought you will like it if the code is close to C programming. For compactness, I have now made the changes as you want.